# Change NSLayoutConstraint within UIView Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to affect the `NSLayoutConstraint` within my `UIView` subclass. However where ever I put the code it doesn't seem to change the autolayout constraint.
 I have used `NSLayoutConstraint` many times before but for some reason cannot seem to reference it in the subclass.

My constraint is

```
self.ripHeight.constant
```

Connected by

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *ripHeight;
```

I have tried it in the `init` and `awakeFromNib` methods as below

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        //self.ripHeight.constant = 100;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    // 2 . Change Height of Ripll Container to suit device - bitch
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    //Create Nib Frame
    CGRect frameRect = self.frame;
    frameRect.size.width = screenWidth;
    frameRect.size.height = screenWidth * 1.3333;
    self.frame = frameRect;

    self.ripHeight.constant = 100;

}
```

I am loading the view in by

```
[self.ripContainer addSubview:customView];
```

Comment: how do you connect the property rip height to your constraint your code should work - make sure the NSLayoutConstriants are setup when doing that call. In init is too early.

Comment: where do you set the `ripHeight` ? Can you add the declaration of this property?

Comment: I connected the property as shown above in the code. This is within a Nib.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint before setting the constant to 100 and check your `ripHeight` is it a not nil value?

Comment: @Otávio No its 450 because of autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update layout manually once you have changed the constraint :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];
    //...
    //your code for constraint

    [self.superview setNeedsLayout];
}
```

[- setNeedsLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsLayout)

> Invalidates the current layout of the receiver and triggers a layout
>   update during the next update cycle.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you
>   want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a
>   note of the request and returns immediately. Because this method does
>   not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update
>   cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views
>   before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to
>   consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is
>   usually better for performance.

Comment: then just after setNeedsLayout, doing [self.superview layoutIfNeeded];  ?

Comment: Was my last comment the complementary solution to make it work? if so I'll edit my answer to add it

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach to resolve this type of issue is using `awakeAfterUsingCoder`.
 It works as a placeholder view. Load your view here instead of in ViewController. Also set layout constraints right in the XIB.

For more information see [this](http://www.secretlab.com.au/blog/2012/06/17/embedding-external-nibs-for-fun-and-profit) link.